# Entity Framework Auto Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I am learning to develop project using code first approach. I am facing a small problem that when i run the command Add-Migration its not identifying the changes even i have enables the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled in config file

here is my code
----------------------------- DbContext file

```
 using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace EntityCodeFirstSample.DataBaseFiles
    {
        class EntityCodeFirstSampleContext : DbContext
        {

            public EntityCodeFirstSampleContext()
                : base("name=DbConnectionString")
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EntityCodeFirstSampleContext, EntityCodeFirstSample.Migrations.Configuration>("DbConnectionString"));
            }

            public DbSet<Publisher> Publishers { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Venkat> Venkats { get; set; }

        }
    }
----------------- Configurations file ---------------------------------
    namespace EntityCodeFirstSample.Migrations
    {
        internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<EntityCodeFirstSample.DataBaseFiles.EntityCodeFirstSampleContext>
        {
            public Configuration()
            {
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
                AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            }

            protected override void Seed(EntityCodeFirstSample.DataBaseFiles.EntityCodeFirstSampleContext context)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

------------------------------------------- Model File ---------------------

```
namespace EntityCodeFirstSample.DataBaseFiles
{
    [Table("Venkat")]
    public class Venkat
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int NotaryCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After running the command Add-Migration VenkatClass it is generating the migration file as below

```
namespace EntityCodeFirstSample.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class VenkatClass : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true then you don't have to add Migration because when you will execute your program the EF will look after for any change on the fly and update your database. If you want to control  then set the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false. Then you should be able to see the difference when Add-Migration is being called.

Please read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx

and then read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Run:

> update-database

Make sure that the project is set default where the connection string is stored.

If it does not return any error then it is all good to go. You should able to see that the update has already occured and your new changes must have reflect already.

Comment: hi thanks for your replay. as you mentioned i have executed the command update-database but it didn't created the table Venkat in the database. can you please help me why it is not creating the table

Comment: Please give the output of the update-database; was it successful?